Can $K$ different discrete-time martingale difference sequence share same filtration?
Consider $K$ different discrete-time stochastic processes $X_j$, where $\mathbb{E}\left[X_j(t)|\mathcal{F}_{t-1}\right]=0$ for each $j\in[K]$ and $t\in\mathbb{N}$, where $\mathcal{F}_{t-1}=\sigma(X_1(t-1),\ldots,X_K(t-1))$. And $\mathbb{E}\left[|X_j(t)|\right]<\infty$ for all $j$ and $t$. Can we say $X_j$ is a martingale difference sequence with respect to $\mathcal{F}_t$ and use Martingale-type inequalities? I cannot easily find references for this kind of setting, which keywords should I search for?

First of all, $(\mathcal F_t)$ is not a filtration since the inclusion $\mathcal F_{t}\subset\mathcal{F}_{t'}$ does not hold for $t\leq t'$. Do you rather have $\mathcal F_t=\sigma(X_k(s),1\leq k\leq K,s\leq t)$?
